# What is a line in a file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I am trying to make a short program like this

```
    <?php
$fname=$lname="";
$line;
$linecount=0;
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $file=fopen("ques4.txt","a+");
    fputs($file,$fname);
    fputs($file,"<br/>");
    fputs($file,$lname);
    fclose($file);
    $file=fopen("ques4.txt","r");
        while(!feof($file))
    {
        echo fgets($file)."<br>";
            $linecount++;
    }
    echo $linecount;
    fclose($file);

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label for="FName">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname">
        <label for="Lname">Last name</label><input type="text" name="lname">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click me">
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

now the $linecount is always 1 means only 1 line is generated.
I want to ask what is considered as a line in PHP, and how can i print a line with break tag given in echo statement.

Like when i write to a file a line should be generated automatically and when i print all the content should appear one line after the other.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php -- I believe anytime a "newline" ("\n" or linefeed) is met.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP_EOL constant instead of "br". It will output \n or \n\r according to your platform.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP file functions work based on UNIX file conventions. A new line starts each time a `\n` character is encountered. A `<br />` tag will not start a new line. It is only for display purpose.